# How to find the convex hull of the set $\left\{ {\bf x} \in \{0, 1 \}^n \mid {\bf 1}_n^\top {\bf x} = k \right\}$?

Tags: convex-analysis, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls, bit-strings

Given integers $k < n$, let

$$ \mathcal{V} := \left\{ {\bf x} \in \{0, 1 \}^n \mid {\bf 1}_n^\top {\bf x} = k \right\} $$

Is it true that its convex hull is $\mathcal{S} := \left\{ {\bf x} \in[0,1]^n \mid {\bf 1}_n^\top {\bf x} = k \right\}$?

Because, it holds for $n>1$ and $k=1$, i.e., the unit simplex is the convex hull of the standard basis. But when I think about $k>1$, things seem to go crazy. Any good ideas or good references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Imagine a cube, with a plane diagonally intersecting it through some of the corners. This should give you a good intuition for the higher dimensional case. You should be able to see geometrically what the hull is in the cube case. And yes, your guess about the hull is correct.

Comment: You just need to prove that any point in S that is not in V is not an extremal point (vertex) and it is quite easy to do. Then you use the fact that any convex polytope is the convex hull of its vertices

Comment: @ZoeAllen thanks! I can imagine that, but I was kind of struggling to express an arbitrary element in $\mathcal{S}$ by a convex combination of some elements in $\mathcal{V}$. Exodd's suggestion seems promising, i.e., proof that elements in $\mathcal{V}$ are vertices. Let me have a try.

Comment: @Exodd thank you so much! sounds promising, I will have a try.

Comment: I'd suggest the following approach: for $v\in S$. If the minimal $v_i$ is $0$, discard the coordinate $i$ and use induction, if not, select any other $k-1$ coordinate, $v=v_i*w+(1-v_i)*u$, which $w_j=1$ iff $j=i$ or in the choosen $k-1$ coordinate and $0$ otherwise. $u_i=0$ and other component in $\[0,1\]$. Thus reduct to first case.

Comment: Note that $\mathcal V$ is the set of vertices of the $n$-dimensional hypercube with Hamming weight $k$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks!

Comment: @PeterWu thank you. not fully understood, I will think about it

Comment: perhaps a bit more obscure: the fact that $\mathbf v =\sum_{j=1}^k \mathbf e_j\succeq \mathbf x \in \mathcal{S}$ makes the result immediate when you know the theory of majorization (the $\succeq$ symbol reads: "majorizes"), since it tells us that $D\mathbf v = \mathbf x$ where $D$ is doubly stochastic hence in the convex hull of $n\times n$ permutation matrices per Birkhoff-von Neumann.